# What to do when you find a bad link in an answer?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

If a link has gone stale in an answer, what is the correct way to report this in the SO universe?

e.g. Jon's first link in

[Bad Link Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194304/whats-the-best-way-to-write-0-100-in-c/194307#194307)

I have added a comment but not found the correct link yet.

Comment: The link in question works for me... what problem are you having?

Comment: Ok the link is fine, now but the question still stands

Comment: Related question when the link is not merely bad, but downright evil (malware): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101318/should-this-answer-be-deleted-due-to-linking-to-potentially-malicious-content

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can edit it with a correct one, then I would do so...  If the link is bad, and the correct one cannot be determined, I'd edit the question/answer and note that the URL was not working as of MM/DD/YYYY...

I would also add a comment to the question/answer informing the poster that there was an issue with the link (you can do this regardless of ability to edit)...